# Is CHARACTER SET redundant when specifying COLLATION in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've always been surprised that MySQL and related tools tend to specify both `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` in `CREATE TABLE` AND `ALTER TABLE` statements:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE ...
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When I select a collation for a column in MySQL Workbench, I get:

```
ALTER TABLE ...
CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' ...;
```

I've always supposed that specifying the character set **and** the collation was redundant, as the collation implies the character set.

**Am I wrong?**

When I try to mix a collation with another charset, I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 collate latin1_bin;
```

> COLLATION 'latin1_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

**Is it safe to only ever specify the collation?**

If so, why do all these tools systematically include the charset in the statement, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not required to specify *character set* when creating table, it's automatically set on *collate* as it described in the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html):

> MySQL chooses the table character set and collation in the following
>   manner:
>
> - If both CHARACTER SET *charset_name* and COLLATE *collation_name* are    specified, character set *charset_name* and collation *collation_name* are used.
> - If CHARACTER SET *charset_name* is specified without COLLATE, character set *charset_name* and its default collation are used. To see the default collation for each character set, use the [SHOW CHARACTER SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-character-set.html) statement or query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA [CHARACTER_SETS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/character-sets-table.html) table.
> - If COLLATE *collation_name* is specified without CHARACTER SET, the character set associated with *collation_name* and collation *collation_name* are used.
> - Otherwise (neither CHARACTER SET nor COLLATE is specified), the database character set and collation are used.
>
> The table *character set* and *collation* are used as default values
>   for column definitions if the column character set and collation are
>   not specified in individual column definitions. The table character
>   set and collation are **MySQL extensions**; there are no such things
>   in standard SQL.

So you can create a table using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabletest` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

This query will create a table with `CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci`, so it's safe to specify COLLATE only.

As for why are there both CHARSET and COLLATE, please read the following:

- [What is the difference between collation and character set?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95048/what-is-the-difference-between-collation-and-character-set)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the MariaDB doc. That makes me more confident specifying the collation only!